# cannot find symbol symbol: class NestableRuntimeException location: package org.hibernate.exception

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, orm, dependencies

I have following maven dependency in my `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>
```

But after project compile I see following message:

```
cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class NestableRuntimeException
  location: package org.hibernate.exception
```

**P.S.**
I tryed to change hibernate version to

4.3.7.Final

But I see old result

Which dependency should I add?

Comment: You can use maven central's search by class name to find the artifacts that contain a particular class: http://search.maven.org/#advancedsearch|gav

Comment: It appears that the NestableRuntimeException was removed from hibernate-core between version 3.3.1 and 3.3.2. Unfortunately the class was never deprecated (at least as far as I can tell) and there are no release notes (that I can find) detailing why it was removed.

Comment: Anyway my guess is that it is not a problem with your `hibernate-core` dependency in itself but rather some other dependency you are using is expecting an older version of hibernate. Can you include more of the `dependencies` section from your pom, and also more of the error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [NestableRuntimeException](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/org/hibernate/exception/NestableRuntimeException.html) was available in Hibernate 3.2 but it got removed since [Hibernate 3.3](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/api/org/hibernate/exception/).

You need to refactor your code to use [HibernateException](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/api/org/hibernate/HibernateException.html) instead.